# Screenscraping a page to inject HTML into a MasterPage using C# and MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, screen-scraping

I want to develop a way in which it would be possible to wrap a .Net MVC web application with the correct look and feel of the site to which it is to be linked to.

Basically I want to store a URL of a 'reference page' for the encompassing site which my application will use to screenscrape the header/footer HTML from to use in its Master Page.

So, if/when the site (output from a CMS) changes its structure/images/colours my application will simply use the newly created 'template' and wrap itself accordingly.

There are set start/end div tags in the 'template' being used so I just need to screenscrape the HTML, split it at the relevant points and somehow inject it into the MasterPage for my app.

The screenscraping part looks reasonably straightforward, it's the injection into the Master Page which I am having problems sorting out.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

EDIT - I am currently planning this in my head and have no code to post. As I say, the screenscraping part looks fine, but how would I go about inserting/injecting the relevant HTML extracted from the 'reference page' for the header/footer into the Master Page being used by my application?

Comment: Hi MrSharky - unfortunately, this question (?) is too broad in scope and is rather unclear in terms of what actual help you are looking for. You have described quite a lot but didn't explain where you are having problems, what you have tried and the kind of help you need.

Comment: Can you have literals in masterpages? You could just scrape the header html and store it in a string, then set the literal = the header string in the masterpage codebehind

Comment: @Oded Apologies, it isn't much of a question at present, you are correct. I'll edit it to be a bit more specific. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably already solved this but here is a solution that works with master pages and MVC (and ASP.Net forms as well).

I first tried overriding the Render method of the master page and using RenderControl to render the ContentPlaceHolders, and replacing certain tags in the template with the rendered result. This works for ASP.Net forms but doesn't work for MVC - this way `<% using (Html.BeginForm("A","B")) { %>` always results in a form tag being rendered at the very top of the page, before the doctype.

**Solution**

Retrieve the template and split it into its parts, some are text parts and some are placeholder parts. In your master page, you have a HTML document and your placeholders - not only your placeholders. This way the VS designer will not complain. When rendering, however, you start by clearing the Controls collection and then add each part as either a LiteralControl or a ContentPlaceHolder. You just leave the actual rendering to ASP.Net. Below is code for inspiration.

Master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title runat="server"></title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="HeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cnnet/Resources/Js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Master page code-behind:

```
private HtmlHead originalPageHeader;
static readonly Regex HeadStartRegex = new Regex(@"^\s*<head[^>]*>");
static readonly Regex HeadEndRegex = new Regex(@"</head>\s*$");
static readonly Regex TitleRegex = new Regex(@"<title>[^<]*</title>");

public Default() { Init += Default_Init; }

private void Default_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) { DoScraping(); }

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // get content from html head control generated via Page.Header:
    string headHtml = RenderControl(originalPageHeader);
    Controls.Remove(originalPageHeader);
    headHtml = HeadStartRegex.Replace(headHtml, string.Empty);
    headHtml = HeadEndRegex.Replace(headHtml, string.Empty);
    headHtml = TitleRegex.Replace(headHtml, string.Empty);
    // head.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(headHtml)); doesnt work if head content placeholder contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)
    // Instead add content this way:
    int headIndex = Controls.IndexOf(HeadContentPlaceHolder);
    if (headIndex != -1)
        Controls.AddAt(headIndex + 1, new LiteralControl(headHtml));

    base.Render(writer);
}

private void DoScraping()
{
    IList<PagePart> parts = ... // do your scraping and splitting into parts
    Controls.Clear();

    foreach (PagePart part in parts)
    {
        var literalPart = part as LiteralPart;
        if (literalPart != null)
        {
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(literalPart.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            var placeHolderPart = part as PlaceHolderPart;
            switch (placeHolderPart.Type)
            {
                case PlaceHolderType.Title:
                    Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Page.Title)));
                    break;
                case PlaceHolderType.Head:
                    Controls.Add(HeadPlaceHolder);
                    Controls.Add(HeadContentPlaceHolder);
                    break;
                case PlaceHolderType.Main:
                    Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='boxContent'>"));
                    Controls.Add(MainContentPlaceHolder);
                    Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div/>"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    string innerHtml;
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            control.RenderControl(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            innerHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
    return innerHtml;
}
```

Parts:

```
public class PagePart {}

public class LiteralPart : PagePart
{
    public LiteralPart(string text) { Text = text; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
}

public class PlaceHolderPart : PagePart
{
    public PlaceHolderPart(PlaceHolderType type) { Type = type; }
    public PlaceHolderType Type { get; private set; }
}

public enum PlaceHolderType { Title, Head, Main }
```

For splitting:

```
class PlaceHolderInfo
{
    public PlaceHolderInfo(PlaceHolderType type, Regex splitter)
    {
        Type = type;
        Splitter = splitter;
    }

    public PlaceHolderType Type { get; private set; }
    public Regex Splitter { get; private set; }
}

private static readonly List<PlaceHolderInfo> PlaceHolderInfos = new List<PlaceHolderInfo>
    {
        new PlaceHolderInfo(PlaceHolderType.Title, new Regex(TitleString)),
        new PlaceHolderInfo(PlaceHolderType.Head, new Regex(HeadString)),
        new PlaceHolderInfo(PlaceHolderType.Main, new Regex(MainString)),
    };

private static List<PagePart> SplitPage(string html)
{
    var parts = new List<PagePart>(new PagePart[] { new LiteralPart(html) });
    foreach (PlaceHolderInfo info in placeHolderInfos)
    {
        var newParts = new List<PagePart>();
        foreach (PagePart part in parts)
        {
            if (part is PlaceHolderPart)
            {
                newParts.Add(part);
            }
            else
            {
                var literalPart = (LiteralPart)part;
                // Note about Regex.Split: if match is found in beginning or end of string, an empty string is returned in corresponding end of returned array.
                string[] split = info.Splitter.Split(literalPart.Text); 
                for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                {
                    newParts.Add(new LiteralPart(split[i]));
                    if (i + 1 < split.Length) // If result of Split returned more than one string, it means there was a match and we insert the placeholder between each string
                        newParts.Add(new PlaceHolderPart(info.Type));
                }
            }
        }
        parts = newParts;
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Note that this solution is easy to expand to more placeholders (breadcrumb, menu, you name it). It makes no assumption as to the order of the placeholders in the template or to the existance of them.

Edit 1:
I originally called `DoScraping` from the `Render` method. It turned out to be problematic because it did renumbering of control names in web forms (such as ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$RequestingRepeater$ctl01$ctl01). It messed up the numbers to the point where `OnCommand` in buttons inside repeaters stopped working. Reordering of controls has to happen as early as possible to avoid this so it has been moved to `Init` now.

Edit 2:
Some pages use `Page.Header` to generate style and script tags. To support this functionality I have added some hacks to keep the original `<head>` tag and insert the generated content when rendering.